# Adjustment for confounders

Tags: median, epidemiology, confounding

I have some epidemiological data, relating to the prevalence of obesity at UK local authority level. For the purpose of exploration I want to derive the median obesity prevalence. However, I need to account/adjust for measures of deprivation and ethnicity.

What methods are there for deriving an adjusted median value?

Comment: If you do your adjustments appropriately then the mean of the adjusted local authority data (suitably weighted for population: Birmingham has over 25 times the population of Rutland) should come up with the unadjusted national prevalence rate, and this will provide a consistency check on your adjustments.  You will then have adjusted figures for each local authority, and you can do what you like with those (including taking some kind of median, though personally I would stick with the national prevalence rate as the most easily understood central figure).

Comment: Why is it important to estimate the median rather than the mean? Are there a lot of high-obesity areas and a few low-obesity areas or a lot of low-obesity areas and a few high-obesity areas?